# How do I make Contact form 7 full page width?

Tags: wordpress, contact-form-7

I am creating a contact form in WordPress with contact form 7, but I cant see how to make it full page width.

I have tried the following suggestions but without success:

div.wpcf7{width:100% !important;}

This suggestion only worked once, and when i changed the form name, the code didnt work anymore.

I have also tried the following:
.wpcf7{width:100% !important;}

and
.wpcf7-form{width:100% !important;}

all of these suggestions, do not seem to have affect on the width of the form.

please help, I have been searching the net and trying suggestions, but without affect.

your help is much appreciated.

```
enter code here


<form method="post" action="#">
                        <div class="inquiry-form">
                <h3 class="inquiry-title">Enquire about this property</h3>
                <div role="form" class="wpcf7" id="wpcf7-f12490-p12399-o1" lang="en-GB" dir="ltr">
<div class="screen-reader-response"></div>
<form action="/property/detached-mediterranean-style-villa-in-cabo-roig/#wpcf7-f12490-p12399-o1" method="post" class="wpcf7-form" novalidate="novalidate">
<div style="display: none;">
<input type="hidden" name="_wpcf7" value="12490" />
<input type="hidden" name="_wpcf7_version" value="5.0.4" />
<input type="hidden" name="_wpcf7_locale" value="en_GB" />
<input type="hidden" name="_wpcf7_unit_tag" value="wpcf7-f12490-p12399-o1" />
<input type="hidden" name="_wpcf7_container_post" value="12399" />
</div>
<p><label> Your Name (required)<br />
    <span class="wpcf7-form-control-wrap your-name"><input type="text" name="your-name" value="" size="40" class="wpcf7-form-control wpcf7-text wpcf7-validates-as-required" aria-required="true" aria-invalid="false" /></span> </label></p>
<p><label> Your Email (required)<br />
    <span class="wpcf7-form-control-wrap your-email"><input type="email" name="your-email" value="" size="40" class="wpcf7-form-control wpcf7-text wpcf7-email wpcf7-validates-as-required wpcf7-validates-as-email" aria-required="true" aria-invalid="false" /></span> </label></p>
<p><label> Subject<br />
    <span class="wpcf7-form-control-wrap your-subject"><input type="text" name="your-subject" value="" size="40" class="wpcf7-form-control wpcf7-text" aria-invalid="false" /></span> </label></p>
<p><label> Your Message<br />
    <span class="wpcf7-form-control-wrap your-message"><textarea name="your-message" cols="40" rows="10" class="wpcf7-form-control wpcf7-textarea" aria-invalid="false"></textarea></span> </label></p>
<p><input type="submit" value="Send" class="wpcf7-form-control wpcf7-submit" /></p>
<input type='hidden' class='wpcf7-pum' value='{"closepopup":false,"closedelay":0,"openpopup":false,"openpopup_id":0}' /><div class="wpcf7-response-output wpcf7-display-none"></div></form></div>            </div>
        </form>
```

Comment: check the width of container where the contact form is

Comment: I would be cool to post the HTML structure containing the form, so we can see what could restrict the full-width.

Comment: Thanks for the replies.

Comment: I can seem to enter the code, its too

Comment: posting code in original post. thx